# How to mock stdin when using fileinput module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, stdin

I have a program that uses the Python `fileinput` module, and I am trying to write unittests for the `main()` function.  They work find when using an actual file, but raise `OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured` when I try to pass data via stdin.  What is the correct way to mock the stdin input when using `fileinput`?

Example `my_fileinput.py`:

```
"""
$ echo "42" | python3.8 my_fileinput.py -
answer: 42
"""

import fileinput
import sys

def main():
    for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1:]):
        sys.stdout.write(f"answer #{fileinput.lineno()}: {line}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example `test_my_fileinput.py`:

```
"""
$ python3.10 -m pytest test_my_fileinput.py
OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured
"""

import io
from unittest import mock

import my_fileinput

def test_stdin():
    """Test fileinput with stdin."""

    with mock.patch.object(my_fileinput, "raw_input", create=True, return_value="42"):
        with mock.patch("sys.stdout", new=io.StringIO()) as stdout:
            with mock.patch("sys.argv", ["my_fileinput.py", "-"]):
                # Raises OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured
                my_fileinput.main()
                assert stdout.getvalue() == "answer #1: 42"
```

I have tried various ways of mocking stdin, all with the same results.  All result in the same OSError.

Comment: Why test that `fileinput.input` works correctly? *Your* test need only ensure that whatever `fileinput.input` *returns* is iterated over correctly. I would just mock the function itself to provide a sufficient iterable for testing.

Comment: Because my code also uses other methods from `fileinput` such as `fileinput.lineno()`. and `fileinput.isstdin()`.

Comment: So? What `fileinput` does is not as important as how your code uses what it *produces*.

Comment: So, shouldn't the output be expected output be `"answer #1: 42"` now that you have modified the code under test?  Where did the #lineno go?  The usage example in the docstring doesn't match the behavior of your code anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** A different version patching `sys.stdin` instead of `inputfile.input`

```
import io

from unittest import mock

import my_fileinput

def test_stdin():
    """Test fileinput with stdin."""

    with mock.patch("sys.stdin", new=io.StringIO("42\n")):
        with mock.patch("sys.stdout", new=io.StringIO()) as stdout:
            with mock.patch("sys.argv", ["my_fileinput.py", "-"]):
                my_fileinput.main()
                assert stdout.getvalue() == "answer: 42\n"
```

---

**Warning:** The original answer gets rid of the `OSError`, but renders other functions in the `inputfile` module unusable (see comments).

**Original:**
Changing the first two arguments of `mock.patch.object` to `fileinput` and `"input"` seems to fix the `OSError`.

```
with mock.patch.object(fileinput, "input", create=True, return_value="42"):
```

The first argument is the target object you want to patch, which is the `fileinput` module. The second argument is the attribute to be changed in target object, which is `input`.

```
import io
import fileinput
from unittest import mock

import my_fileinput

def test_stdin():
    """Test fileinput with stdin."""

    with mock.patch.object(fileinput, "input", create=True, return_value="42"):
        with mock.patch("sys.stdout", new=io.StringIO()) as stdout:
            with mock.patch("sys.argv", ["my_fileinput.py", "-"]):
                my_fileinput.main()
                assert stdout.getvalue() == "answer: 42\n"
```

Comment: Although it did fix the original exception, the final assert fails: `AssertionError: assert 'answer: 4answer: 2' == 'answer: 42\n'`.  It appears that the `return_value` must be wrapped in `io.StringIO()`.  So the correct mock code is: `with mock.patch.object(my_fileinput.fileinput, "input", create=True, return_value=io.StringIO("42")):`

Comment: @tschutter Indeed, that makes the for loop iterate over lines of text instead of characters in a string. Also, the assert doesn't need a `\n` at the end.

Comment: Upon further testing, this does not resolve the problem.  This solution allows iteration over `fileinput.input`, but then none of the other `fileinput` functionality works such as `fileinput.lineno()`.  This can be demonstrated by replacing the call to `write()` in `my_fileinput.py` with `sys.stdout.write(f"answer #{fileinput.lineno()}: {line}")`.

Comment: @tschutter I updated my answer with an alternative solution at the bottom. Can you check if it works?

Comment: I tried your alternative solution and it works (with an adjustment to the final assert).  Thanks!

Comment: Nice, good to know. If you don't mind, I'll be removing the previous solution that didn't work shortly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary for you to test [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) itself, since that will be tested by CPython's own test suite: [`Lib/test/test_fileinput.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/test/test_fileinput.py). The pytesthonic way to test *your code* would be like this, using fixtures:

```
import my_fileinput

def test_stdin(mocker, capsys):
    mocker.patch("fileinput.lineno", return_value=1)
    mocker.patch("fileinput.input", return_value=["42\n"])
    my_fileinput.main()
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == "answer #1: 42\n"
```

The `capsys` fixture is included with pytest, and the `mocker` fixture is provided by plugin [pytest-mock](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: This seems to suffer from the same issue as pointed out by @tschutter under my answer.

Comment: @Fractalism Works for me.  Did you copy this code exactly, or did you use `return_value="42"`?

Comment: Copypasted your code into `test_my_fileinput.py`, replaced the `sys.stdout` line with `sys.stdout.write(f"answer #{fileinput.lineno()}: {line}")` in `my_fileinput.py`, and then the test fails with `RuntimeError: no active input()`

Comment: Why "_replaced the `sys.stdout` line with..._"? My test works on the O.P. code unmodified.

Comment: Because in his comment "*Upon further testing, this does not resolve the problem.*" he evidently wants `fileinput.lineno` to be usable as well.

Comment: This question is not about testing `fileinput`.  It is about testing a system that uses `fileinput`.  And `fileinput` has much more functionality than just being a generator of lines.  Fractalism's alternative solution solved the problem correctly.

Comment: @Fractalism Edited to include the patch on lineno too. That was not in the original question, and users can't be expected to trawl through comments underneath other answers looking for updates - these need to be _edited into the question_.